# IE 7 hasLayout Bug on li class

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, haslayout

I have created a navigation for a WP theme that uses the classes that are written out via the CMS on to the "li" element and not the "a" class.

As a result on IE7 there is a hasLayout but on the navigation when you hover over a link, the whole element moves up and stays there.

On inspecting the code the hasLayout is -1 and I've tried all the hacks that I can find on google but none have worked.

Is anyone able to take a look, the site is here and it is the first menu that has  "total care/Personal Injury/Blog"

Site: http://staging.watermans.ws/blog/